# Why I'm getting pure json data which can't be displayed

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to build a simple web which has 2 function:
1. get string (sms) message from server, and display it on screen
2. send (post) form data to server which send back the data, which will be logged.

The server code:

```
app.get('/sms', function (req, res) {   
   var smsMsg = fs.readFileSync('sms.txt');
   console.log('Read File: ' + smsMsg.toString());
   res.send(smsMsg.toString());   
})

app.post('/result', function (req, res) {      
   console.log('Got Personal Information: ' + req.body.firstName + " " + req.body.lastName);   

   response = {
       first_name:req.body.firstName,
       last_name:req.body.lastName,
       id:'0399'
   };
   console.log(response);

   // value to a JSON string 
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  
   res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

The client code:

```
<body>      

     <p>    
        <button onclick="sendRequestForSms()"> Get SMS From Server </button>
        </br>
        <h1 id="smsId"> SMS: <h1>
        </br>
     </p>
     <p>
        <form action="/result" method="post">       
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal information:</legend>
                 First name: 
                <input type="text" name="firstName">
                <br>
                Last name:
                <input type="text" name="lastName">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form> 
     </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">


            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else 
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {       
                  console.log('State: ' + xmlhttp.readyState + ' status: ' + xmlhttp.status);           
                  // 1: server connection established
                  // 4: request finished and response is ready
                  // 200: "OK"
                  // 404: Page not found
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
                  {
                        if (xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') == 'application/json') 
                        {
                            console.log('Got Json');
                            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                            console.log(myArr);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            document.getElementById("smsId").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;  
                        }   


                  }
            };

            function sendRequestForSms() {              
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "/sms", true);
                xmlhttp.send();     
            }                                       
        </script>

</body>
```

- When the user click on 'Get SMS From Server' I'm getting the result and display it on the relevant element ('smsId').
- But :( When the user submit the form, I'm getting new page with json data (for example: '{"first_name":"test1","last_name":"test2","id":"0399"}')
  so I the client code line: `console.log('Got Json');`
  is not reached,  why the client callback function isn't called ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You don't have any code to handle that, so the browser POSTs the form and loads the result as normal.

Comment: Is the server printing ````Got Personal Information?````

Answer (score 0):

`Got Json` is never going to be printed because `/result` (server) is currently set up to just echo the JSON it gets sent. It looks like it's being sent the correct info from the form, but the way you have it set up right now "Got Json" will only print from your "Get SMS" button. To do what you're trying to do, the way you're trying to do it, you would need to make `/result` output a new page that prints out the javascript you want to run after they submit. Does that make sense? I can clarify.

> **Example on the use of XMLHTTPRequest**

```
<div id="id01"></div>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

Live Example: http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_http